# encoding utf 8 java jdbc oracle

Tags: java, sql, jsp, servlets, encoding

Hello i have 3 projects .

1. web application encoding utf-8 . There is servlets, jsp ,html pages etc
2. java app project - utf8 - classes to set a jdbc connection do database oracle
3. another java app project - also utf8 - classes with setters and getters , nothing much

And here is my prolem : When i dispaly something on page all chars are fine, but when i do insert to database by my website i get "ÄÄÅ¼Åº" etc indestead of normall chars. I have no idea what to do. I can see wrong chars in my logs with insert to database so it's java problem.
I use oracle sql developer, netbeans 8.0 and apache tomcat

Answer (score 0):

I know that there are some problems with java and utf-8, had them in my proejcts, m/b [this](http://tripoverit.blogspot.ru/2007/04/javas-utf-8-and-unicode-writing-is.html) link can help you. There you can find some fixes, hope it will be helpful.

Comment: you was using it in your project ? I will try it out but srsly there is no other way ;p ? I though that my settings of project were wrong.

Comment: It was a local project I've changed the encoding to 1251, for utf-8 there is a problem, why that happens I can't say for shure, but I don't know other ways to solve this problem)